# Golang каналы - как работают

Tags: golang, channels

Объясните, пожалуйста, как работает код? и как сделать так, чтобы он работал за 3 секунды?

```
func worker() chan int {
   ch := make(chan int)

   go func() {
      time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
      ch <- 42
   }()

   return ch
}

func main() {
   timeStart := time.Now()

   _, _ = <-worker(), <-worker()

   println(int(time.Since(timeStart).Seconds()))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ключевая проблема здесь в том,
что в этом присвоении
каждый из воркеров отрабатывает последовательно
(несмотря на их внутреннюю конкурентность),
и задержка у вас таким образом суммируется:

```
_, _ = <-worker(), <-worker()
```

Один из способов, в дополнение к тем,
которые приводит KoVadim, было
бы запускать воркеры не последовательно,
а параллельно.

### Горутины

В простейшем случае, когда воркеры работают как обычные функции и не выполняются
в фоне, их можно было бы распареллелить,
обернув вызов каждого в горутину:

```
go func() {
  _ = <-worker()
}()
```

При этом вам нужно координировать их работу, и ждать пока они оба завершатся, например через `WaitGroup` или как либо-ещё.

Вот как обычно это делается через
`WaitGroup` (это требует небольшой модификации вашего кода):

```
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 1; i <= 2; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(i, &wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()
```

То есть, при создании каждого воркера (который запускается на фоне), мы увеличиваем значение счётчика внутри `wg`.

После того как все воркеры запущены,
мы ожидаем их заверешения `wg.Wait()`.

Внутри же воркера вам нужно в таком случае
добавить вызов:

```
  defer wg.Done()
```

который будет сигнализировать о том, что воркер завершился (и уменьшать значение счётчика WaitGroup)

### `select`

В том случае, если воркеры сами по себе
исполняются конкурентно (как раз в нашем случае) и нужно просто вызвать их так,
чтобы они не блокировали друг друга,
можно воспользоваться `select`:

```
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        select {
        case _ = <-worker():
            fmt.Println("worker finished")
        case _ = <-worker():
            fmt.Println("worker finished")
        }
    }
```

(идеально было бы чтобы воркеры различались
каким-то образом, например, с помощью аргумента, который мы бы ему передавали,
но в задаче они никак не различаются — хорошо)

При таком вызове они будут испольняться независимо друг от друга и друг друга блокировать не будут.

Comment: да, так получилось, спасибо)

Comment: @Elena: Я, кажется, понял, что имелось в виду в задаче. Я добавил ещё один раздел. Проверьте, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Способ 1:

заменить

```
time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
```

на

```
time.Sleep(1500 * time.Millisecond)
```

Способ 2:

Заменить

```
_, _ = <-worker(), <-worker()
```

на

```
_ = <-worker()
```

А как работают каналы, лучше почитать [стандартную документацию](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels) или [статью на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/490336/)

Comment: спасибо) но я думаю имелось в виду как запустить эту функцию дважды, чтобы они выполнялись параллельно и всего это заняло 3 сек.

Comment: я умею читать мысли, но думаю это не имеется ввиду.